# Angular 8 Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'

Tags: angular

I have a method that I am trying to call every 5 minutes. It basically check a users network connectivity. However I am getting the following error and am not sure why
`Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'`

Here is my code

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = timer(0, 300000).pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.checkNetwork())
      ).subscribe(result => this.statusText = result);
  }


  checkNetwork() {
    this.speedTestService
    .getKbps({
      iterations: 2,
      file: {
        path:
          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Pizigani_1367_Chart_1MB.jpg",
        size: 1024,
        shouldBustCache: true,
      },
      retryDelay: 60000,
    })
    .subscribe((speed) => {
      console.log("Your speed is " + speed);
      if (speed < 0.4) {
        this.errorService.openErrorPopup('Connection has dropped or is too slow.');
        this.logout();
      }
    });
  }
```

The error appears on here `switchMap(() => this.checkNetwork())`, when I call `this.checkNetwork()`

Any help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be :-

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = timer(0, 300000).pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.checkNetwork())
      ).subscribe(result => this.statusText = result);
  }


  checkNetwork() {
    return this.speedTestService
    .getKbps({
      iterations: 2,
      file: {
        path:
          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Pizigani_1367_Chart_1MB.jpg",
        size: 1024,
        shouldBustCache: true,
      },
      retryDelay: 60000,
    })
    .pipe(map((speed) => {
      console.log("Your speed is " + speed);
      if (speed < 0.4) {
        this.errorService.openErrorPopup('Connection has dropped or is too slow.');
        this.logout();
      }
    }));
  }
```

as switch map expects an observable and from checkNetwork you were not returning an Observable, you were just subscribing to one which was not required.

Answer (score 1):

`switchMap` requires Observable to be returned in callback, but you do not return anything.

Try this.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = timer(0, 300000).pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.checkNetwork())
      ).subscribe((speed) => {
        console.log("Your speed is " + speed);
        if (speed < 0.4) {
          this.errorService.openErrorPopup('Connection has dropped or is too slow.');
          this.logout();
        }
        
        this.statusText = ....
        
      });
  }


  checkNetwork() {
     return this.speedTestService.getKbps({
              iterations: 2,
              file: {
              path:
               "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Pizigani_1367_Chart_1MB.jpg",
              size: 1024,
              shouldBustCache: true,
            },
            retryDelay: 60000,
            });
  }
```